# UserProfile model isn't saving ForeignKeys

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, save, user-profile

I followed the following guide: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile and it worked beautifully, except that I can't seem to save ForeignKey's to the user profile.

## Models

**PCBuild model**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class PCBuild(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**UserProfile model**

```
import datetime
import md5

from apps.pcbuilder.models import PCBuild
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):   
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    email_hash = models.CharField(max_length=200) #MD5 hash of e-mail

    current_build = models.ForeignKey(PCBuild, 
        related_name='current_build', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.email 


User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
                            user=u, 
                            email_hash=md5.new(u.email).hexdigest())[0])
```

## Example of problem

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from apps.pcbuilder.models import PCBuild
>>> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

>>> user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=2)
>>> user
    <User: Trevor>

>>> pcbuild = get_object_or_404(PCBuild, pk=11)
>>> pcbuild
    <PCBuild: StackOverflowBuild>

>>> pcbuild.owner
    <User: Trevor>

>>> user.profile.email_hash
    u'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'

>>> user.profile.current_build = pcbuild
>>> user.profile.save()
>>> user.profile.current_build
    # nothing is stored/outputted - this is the problem!
```

I am new to Django, and though Google has been helpful so far, this one I haven't conquered after several hours. If any more information is needed regarding this question I'll be glad to provide it!

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Things I've found that may be useful (but didn't solve my particular problem):

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields
- http://sam.odio.com/blog/2008/05/extending-user-model-profiles-in-django.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to run into misterious bugs down the line by using the property.  Since the `UserProfile` to `User` relation is a `OneToOneField`, you can access the profile instance from the instance by doing `user.userprofile`.  If you'd like to change the name you can update the `OneToOneField`'s `related_name` property.

Use signals to automatically create the profile when a user is created like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    """Create a UserProfile instance when a User is created."""
    u = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
                        user=u, 
                        email_hash=md5.new(u.email).hexdigest())

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I already went ahead and changed everything from `user.profile` to `user.get_profile()` but I'll take note if I want to change the name later.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - but I'm open to other answers still & will check back later. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the lambda function I'm using to get the profile. How I went about it in the python shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from apps.pcbuilder.models import PCBuild
>>> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
>>> user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=2)
>>> user
    <User: Trevor>

>>> pcbuild = get_object_or_404(PCBuild, pk=11)
>>> pcbuild
    <PCBuild: StackOverflowBuild>

>>> user.profile.current_build
    # nothing (which is expected as there is nothing 
    # yet in the current_build of this user profile)


# NOTE: I'm creating a new "profile" variable that holds the user profile.

>>> profile = user.profile
>>> profile
    <UserProfile: Trevor>

>>> profile.current_build
    # nothing (which is expected as there is nothing 
    # yet in the current_build of this user profile)

>>> profile.current_build = pcbuild
>>> profile.save()

>>> user.profile.current_build
    <PCBuild: StackOverflowBuild>

    # As you can see, it worked!
```

I basically had to assign *user.profile* to it's own variable (*profile* in the example), and then after modifying the variable, saving that instead of the user object.

It seems a little awkward, but it works.

Comment: That's going to be very confusing/bug prone down the line.  Just drop the property and use `user.get_profile()`.

Comment: @sdolan I guess my question then is what if the user doesn't have a UserProfile yet (the purpose of the lambda function)? I'll see if using `user.get_profile()` does the trick for users with profiles already. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, that works much better. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. I knew that lambda function was a little fishy.

Comment: Use signals to create one when the `User` instance is created.

Comment: I added an answer on how to do it.